# PrintDocument1_PrintPage vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview, printdocument

i've tried to print a document with many rows in my datagridview and i want to print it continously by having next page with the data not including the 1st page but it gives me the same as 1st page heres my code :

```
 dim i as integer

 Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    i = i + 1
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(Me.Panel2.Width, Me.Panel2.Height)
    Panel2.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Panel2.Width, Me.Panel2.Height))
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0)
    If (i = 1) Then e.HasMorePages = True Else e.HasMorePages = False
    Dim aPS As New PageSetupDialog
    aPS.Document = PrintDocument1

End Sub
```

can anyone help me in this kind of problem
sorry for wrong grammar thanks

Comment: If you are trying to print the rows of a grid, why are you drawing bitmaps of a panel?

Comment: i have a logo and some labels at the top which is in the panel

Comment: What about writing the data to temp file and then grabbing it and printing it? I have accomplished this before; you can loop through your data from the grid and save it to file. Then grab that file and draw the string to bounds to print.

Comment: @MarkLouieAchacoso - refer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView) codeproject article for printing datagridview... its a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is essentially a screen print so what you see is what you get. If you want to stay with this way, you need to advance the rows on the grid so you see different records.

What you should do is look into [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) for a print out that looks like a document instead of a picture.